# JSON.parse with functions inside

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string that if I turn it into OBJ it works correctly.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "placeholder": "Hello...."} ');
```

then I put it in the tagEditor plugin in this way `$('textarea').tagEditor(obj);`

But I also need to evaluate within if there is a function and that it works, in this way.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "placeholder": "Hello....", "onChange":"function(a,b,c)}{ }"} ');
```

and I put it....... `$('textarea').tagEditor(obj);`

but when I do that I get error
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 38**

Actually I want to evaluate the function that is by string, 
As you can see when I put the event "onchange" and the function within the object this has to evaluate it for the plugin to work
Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Comment: See the snippet - your new edited code looks to work fine (or, at least, does not throw a `SyntaxError`)

Comment: tagEditor does not evaluate the object if I put that event, apparently it is an error in the parse, or I do not know =/

Answer (score 1):

You should first declare the function, then call `toString` on the function (which will automatically escape the `'`s, which is the problem in your current syntax):

```js
function x(a, b, c){
  return '';
}
const stringified = JSON.stringify({
  placeholder: "Hello....",
  onChange: x.toString()
});
```

Specifically, because the string delimiters for the function property value use `'`, you need to escape the `'`s used inside. (turn

```
"onChange":"function(a,b,c)}{ return ''; }"
```

into

```
"onChange":"function(a,b,c)}{ return \'\'; }"
```

)

But I wouldn't recommend doing that manually, it'll be pretty tedious and somewhat error-prone - the `toString()` method is probably a better option.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just updated the question, I really need the function to be evaluated

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is invalid:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "placeholder": "Hello....", "onChange":"function(a,b,c)}{ return ''; }"} ');
```

You JSON is quoted properly, but you preempted the single quotes inside the function declaration. So change it to escaped quotes:

EDIT: to then evaluate the function you must use `eval()` like this. I have no idea what your intent is for the onChange handler so I modified it so it would actually work:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "placeholder": "Hello....", "onChange":"function handler(e){ console.log(e.target.value); }"} ');
console.log(obj);
eval(obj.onChange);
document.querySelector('input').onchange = handler;
```

```html
<input>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to fit the "*`Unexpected string in JSON`*" error message though. But your example works, so it must be something else anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just updated the question, I really need the function to be evaluated